# Using TypeKit's WebFontLoader for Canvas text

Tags: javascript, text, canvas, webfonts, webfont-loader

I'm having a hard time using fonts loaded via the **[TypeKit webfontloader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader)** as font faces for text that is drawn on a canvas element.

I boiled it down to the following test case:

```
WebFont.load({
    google: {
      families: ['Droid Sans', 'Droid Serif']
    },
    monotype: {
        projectId: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' //this is valid & working
    },
    fontactive : function(font, fvd){
        testFont(font, fvd, 'active');
    },
    fontinactive : function(font, fvd){
        testFont(font, fvd, 'inactive');
    }
});

function testFont(font, fvd, state){

    console.log('loaded ' + state, font, fvd);

    var $canvas = $('<canvas>').attr({width: 400, height: 100}).appendTo($('body'));
    var canvas = $canvas[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.font = '30px ' + font;
    ctx.fillText('CANVAS PARTY YALL!', 50, 50);

}
```

The callbacks for each font will fire, yet the font isn't used in the canvas text. One strange aspect is that the fonts loaded from fonts.com (the `monotype`) part do declare themselves as `fontinactive`, yet I can apply them to all HTML without problems. The Google fonts will always fire a `fontactive`.

The other strange aspect is that the Google Fonts will display in one of about 20 cases, yet when I wrap my `testFont` function inside a `setTimeout` with a delay of `1000`ms this behavior reverses and makes the fonts.com font display from time to time.

All this leads me to the conclusion that the handlers probably fire too early, but I have no clue what to do about this (instead of hacky stuff like timeouts and praying). Any idea what I am doing wrong or what I could do to fix this?

**EDIT:** To add to the confusion I just noticed that the fonts.com font is actually working perfectly fine in IE9. All other browsers seem to do the things I described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I did find out that everything is working fine when I do not hide elements of `.wf-loading` via my Stylesheet so I do **not** use:

```
.wf-loading{
    display: none;
}
```

anymore but use screen offset to hide unrendered elements.